# angularjs - custom directive in ng-include not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've tried this snippet for using bs3 modal in my application and it works fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/alexsuch/RLQhh/

However,I want to wrap the code of modal and some other html tags into a template for reusability.

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
  <h1>Modal example</h1>
  <button ng-click="toggleModal()" class="btn btn-default">Open modal</button>
    <div ng-include src="'modal.html'"></div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
          <modal title="Login form" visible="showModal">
    <form role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </modal>
    </script>
</div>
```

Here is my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wangjunji/gL7scbd9/

Then comes the question.The toggle button only works for the first time.
I know that ng-include directive will create a child scope which makes the variable in parent scope unreachable but I have no idea to work out this sticky problem.Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: if you remove `scope=true` that means if there is no specific reason to have an isolated scope .your issue will be resolved.If you want isolated scope then you can make that toggle  variable an object property to update the parent scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed your code a little bit so the boolean value will reside inside an object, and now you just have to watch that instead:

Controller changes:

```
mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.modalObj = { showModal : false };
    $scope.toggleModal = function(){
        $scope.modalObj.showModal = !$scope.modalObj.showModal;
    };
  });
```

Directive (main) change:

```
scope.$watch(function () { return scope.modalObj.showModal; }, function(value){
    if(value == true)
      $(element).modal('show');
    else
      $(element).modal('hide');
});
```

And also of course the lines will now refer to `scope.modalObj.showModal` instead of using the parent/attr keywords, in general you should try to avoid those.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seyenaz/gL7scbd9/1/)

Comment: Great work @Omri and one more thing to OP use $observe in case you want to watch the changes on attribute values.

Comment: Great! What if i have two or more modals in the template?

Comment: @user3505525 Probably keep a different object for each one?

Comment: @OmriAharon Can you have a look? How to make the code elegant?  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wangjunji/t13fn08m/1)

Comment: @user3505525 Just add another model, and use isolated scope: http://jsfiddle.net/seyenaz/t13fn08m/2/