# angularjs ng-include and angularjs custom directive dont't want work together

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have angualrjs app and I use login box as popup box. Now all html code of login box is loaded with main html code (work correct), but my goal is get login box html when login button is clicked (for save user resources). I try it do with ng-include. It`s work correct but only one time, if I try click login button again after close login box nothing happens.

First I try bind href for include html when login button is pressed using this function:

```
$scope.toggleLogInForm = function(){

    if(typeof $scope.htmlTemplates.LoginPopupHtml === 'undefined'){
        $scope.htmlTemplates.LoginPopupHtml =  urlSer.url+'html/getLoginPopupHtml';
    }

    $scope.showLogin = true;
    console.log($scope.showLogin); // print true when press login button
}
```

element with `ng-include` atrribute for store html.

```
<div ng-include src="htmlTemplates.LoginPopupHtml"></div>
```

directive for control hide/show login box:

```
webApp.directive('regmodal', function () {
return {
  template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
      '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
        '<div class="">' + 
          '<div class="" ng-transclude></div>' + 
        '</div>' + 
      '</div>' + 
    '</div>',
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  replace:true,
  scope:true,
  link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.title = attrs.title;
    scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
      if(value == true)
        $(element).modal('show');
      else
        $(element).modal('hide');
    });

    $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
      });
    });

    $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
      });
    });
  }
};
});
```

And finally my html login html code :

```
<regmodal  class="form-login-heading" title="Registration" visible="showLogin">     
        <form class="form-login geform" ng-submit="login()">
        ... // skiped not important for example
        </form>
</regmodal>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use watch function like
in controller

```
mymodal.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.modalObj = { showModal : false };
    $scope.toggleModal = function(){
        $scope.modalObj.showModal = !$scope.modalObj.showModal;
    };
  });
```

in directive

```
scope.$watch(function () { return scope.modalObj.showModal; }, function(value){
    if(value == true)
      $(element).modal('show');
    else
      $(element).modal('hide');
});
```

check this one:
[angularjs - custom directive in ng-include not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271874/angularjs-custom-directive-in-ng-include-not-working)